# htaccess force https for certain directories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I'd like to force https in htaccess for the following directories:

- /admin
- /account
- /login
- /contact
- /signin

So far I got the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^admin https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^account https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^login https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^contact https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^signin https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But this only works for the first two directories, '/admin' and '/account', the rest doesn't redirect to https.

Anyone know how to make this work for the rest of the directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only applicable to very next `RewriteRule`. Your multiple rules can be combined into one. Consider this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(admin|account|login|contact|signin) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I noticed you used **off** instead of **=off**. Is there a reason to this, or is it just a typo?

Comment: @Macchiato: I believe both behave same. Did the rule work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me too, but only for all pages except the root in each directory. i.e., https://domain.com/folder/ is not in SSL.